# How to draw horizontal line and place slide up or slide down icon end of the layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I'm creating slide up and slide down option in android. I want to draw horizontal line and place slide up or slide down icon end of the `LinearLayout`.
I used `layout_weight` concept. But the icon size will vary for screen size. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPg7g.jpg)

```
    `<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:weightSum="15"
        >

        <View
            android:background="@color/blue_tint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="14"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/slide_button"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_slide_down"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: post your full layout code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line and image as per  "given image"

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <view
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```